# Delay timer to use a function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do a function that allow me to use another function each 5 seconds. When the first call of function is started another variable will store last execution time.. I calculated the 5 seconds interval and return if 5 seconds not passed.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        last_use = 0
    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def Foo(self):
        elapsed = time.time() - self.GetLastClick()

        if (elapsed > 5)
            print("Wait 5 seconds")
            return

        self.SetLastClick(time.time())

    def SetLastClick(self, arg):
        self.last_use = arg

    def GetLastClick(self):
        return self.last_use
```

However this doesn't work, what i do wrong?
I get errors like Invalid syntax, also something about float
Python27

Comment: "I want to do a function that allow me to use another function each 5 seconds". Do you mean a function that calls another function every 5 seconds?

Comment: No, an delay to use a function.  Use Foo function, wait 5 second, possibility again to use Foo only if 5 seconds passed

Comment: "this doesn't work" how so? What does it do and how does it differ from your expected behaviour? Your code is sadly not even executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code, cleaned up to remove Java-like getter/setter which are not necessary in Python:

```
import time

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_use = 0

    def Foo(self):
        elapsed = time.time() - self.last_use

        if elapsed < 5:
            print("Wait 5 seconds")
            return

        self.last_use = time.time()
        print("Let's Foo!")


mc = MyClass()
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo()
print('wait a bit now...')
time.sleep(5)
mc.Foo()
```

The main syntax error you had was omitting the ':' on your if statement. Logic-wise, your `> 5` should really be `< 5`.

This prints:

```
Let's Foo!
Wait 5 seconds
Wait 5 seconds
Wait 5 seconds
wait a bit now...
Let's Foo!
```

EDIT:
Here is the advanced version, where a `wait_at_least` decorator takes
care of the overhead logic of checking the elapsed time between calls, and your
various `FooX()` methods just do what `FooX()` methods do:

```
def wait_at_least(min_wait_time):
    "a decorator to check if a minimum time has elapsed between calls"
    def _inner(fn):
        # a wrapper to define the last_call value to be preserved 
        # across function calls
        last_call = [0]
        def _inner2(*args, **kwargs):
            # the function that will actually be called, checking the
            # elapsed time and only calling the function if enough time
            # has passed
            elapsed = time.time() - last_call[0]
            if elapsed < min_wait_time:
                msg = "must wait {:.2f} seconds before calling {} again".format(min_wait_time - elapsed, fn.__name__)
                print(msg)
                # consider doing 'raise NotYetException(msg, min_wait_time, elapsed)` 
                # instead of just returning
                return
            last_call[0] = time.time()
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return _inner2
    return _inner


class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @wait_at_least(5)
    def Foo(self):
        print("Let's Foo!")

    @wait_at_least(3)
    def Foo2(self):
        print("We can Foo2!")


mc = MyClass()
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo2()
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo2()
time.sleep(1.5)
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo2()
print('wait a bit now...')
time.sleep(3)
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo2()
print('wait a little bit more...')
time.sleep(2)
mc.Foo()
mc.Foo2()
```

I added Foo2 to show that the two methods keep separate timers, and can take different minimum wait times between calls.

Prints:

```
Let's Foo!
We can Foo2!
must wait 5.00 seconds before calling Foo again
must wait 3.00 seconds before calling Foo2 again
must wait 3.50 seconds before calling Foo again
must wait 1.50 seconds before calling Foo2 again
wait a bit now...
must wait 0.50 seconds before calling Foo again
We can Foo2!
wait a little bit more...
Let's Foo!
must wait 1.00 seconds before calling Foo2 again
```

Comment: Why time.sleep(5) if you already checked seconds in def Foo ?

Comment: So my test code would wait the required time before calling Foo() again

Comment: Now i have just one error. global name 'elapsed' is not defined, i use the decorator

Comment: Ideally, you should have the "not yet" case in `_inner2` raise an exception instead of just returning. In the exception you could pass back the remaining wait time as an attribute on the exception, and the current print string as the exception message. See code edit (declaration of NotYetException left as an exercise).

Comment: elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using a [closure](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure)

```
from time import time

def foo(t, time_to_wait):
   def _foo():
      if (time() - t) > time_to_wait:
         print(f"{time_to_wait} sec passed do something...")
      else:
         print(f"wait {time_to_wait} seconds")
   return _foo
```

---

```
In [14]: func = foo(time()) # pass the current time

In [15]: func()
wait 5 seconds
In [20]: func()
wait 5 seconds

In [21]: func()
5 sec passed do something...
```

Comment: The outer `foo()` could do `t = time()` for itself instead of making the caller pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

Look out this:

```
import time

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_use = 0
    def __del__(self):
        pass

    def Foo(self):
        if(self.last_use == 0):
            print "Started calling Foo"
            self.last_use = time.time
            time.sleep(5)
            self.anotherFunc()
        else:
            self.whileWaiting()

    def anotherFunc(self):
        self.last_use = 0;
        print "called after 5 second"

    def whileWaiting(self):
        print "Hey! I'm waiting while the previous call ends"


obj = MyClass()
obj.Foo();
```

PS: I love JavaScript ;)